# module still works and making troubles after disabling it

Tags: module, magento-1, extensions, debug

I have disabled the module Inchoo_Notes in the app/etc/modules:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Inchoo_Notes>
            <active>false</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Inchoo_Notes>
    </modules>
</config>
```

I get the following error, when I go to configuration of admin panel:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Inchoo_Notes_Helper_Data' not found in Unknown on line 0
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.1100  272464  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   2.4100  569040  Mage::run( ???, ???, ??? )  ..\index.php:83
3   2.4200  1607016 Mage_Core_Model_App->run( ??? ) ..\Mage.php:684
4   9.0870  13877440    Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch( )  ..\App.php:365
5   9.8670  27413680    Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match( ??? )   ..\Front.php:172
6   9.9270  27414968    Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch( ??? ) ..\Standard.php:254
7   15.3740 28651128    Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController->editAction( )   ..\Action.php:418
8   16.3340 34068944    Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Tabs->initTabs( )    ..\ConfigController.php:104
9   41.2180 66104432    Mage::helper( ??? ) ..\Tabs.php:92
Variables in local scope (#9)

$helperClass =string 'Mage_Inchoo_Notes_Helper_Data' (length=29)

$name =string 'inchoo_notes' (length=12)

$registryKey =string '_helper/inchoo_notes' (length=20)
```

I debugged the code and I am seeing that in configuration it is trying to load the tab of Inchoo notes still in here:

\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\System\Config\Tabs.php

```
foreach ($tabs as $tab) {
        $helperName = $configFields->getAttributeModule($tab);
        $label = Mage::helper($helperName)->__((string)$tab->label);

        $this->addTab($tab->getName(), array(
            'label' => $label,
            'class' => (string) $tab->class
        ));
    }
```

and then I debugged further which goes here in Mage.php:

```
public static function helper($name)
{
    $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
    if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
        $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
        self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
    }
    return self::registry($registryKey);
}
```

I am seeing that `self::registry($registryKey)` is false and therefore it goes to  `$helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);` and instead of having Inchoo_Notes_Helper I will have `Mage_Inchoo_Notes_Helper_Data`

why is that????? why even it tries to load it! when I said disable this module? I am frustrated.

by the way cache is **disabled**, I **flushed** the cache so it is not a solution. Also I have the helper for this module, the helper is not missing, therefore this is not a solution either.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is, that the helper is still used, I would assume, Magento tries to translate certain strings in `system.xml` or `adminhtml.xml` or some layout.xml file.

To my mind come two possiblities:

1. Your assumption, the cache is flushed/disabled is wrong
2. You use somewhere `translate="some nodename" module="inchoo_notes"` in an xml file

Or is is used somewhere else.

The easiest is to grep for it (and grep in var/cache too, so you see, when a cache file includes it (there should be none)

Comment: absolutely I had translate="some nodename" but I removed them and it did not work still, why translate would make trouble?

Comment: I did not know grep can be also used in windows, I should try that but I go to var/cache and delete everything, cache should not be the issue

Comment: if I rename Inchoo to _Inchoo, error will go away but if i rename Notes to _Notes the error still remains!

Comment: I installed grep and searched for notes in cache, it is not there

Comment: I believe you, but what you describe doesn't make sense. Obviously the module is still active. But changing the one name of the directory doesn't solve but the other does? Sounds crazy. No idea, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling it from the command

```
bin/magento module:disable <MODULE_NAME>
```

Or try disabling it manually from the config.xml file located in

> app/etc/config.php

Find your module name there and replace 1 with 0 after your module name. Then the following commands to apply the changes.

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

If the changes don't reflect then your module might be dependent on some other module. You should read this [magento documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-enable.html#instgde-cli-subcommands-enable-modules) in that case.